# ASP.NET Core 7.0 Localization problem with shared resources and data-annotations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, localization, data-annotations

having problems with the .net core mvc project localizations again :)

I have configured to use a shared resource for data annotations

```
.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o =>
        {
            o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
            {
                return factory.Create(typeof(SharedResources));
            };
        })
```

but then I have problem using specific resource files for other data annotations.
Example: I have C# class "IndexInputModel" and resource file with the same name "IndexInputModel.en.resx" but strings in this resource are not found. The folder structure is respected.
They are not resolved/found. Only entries in the SharedResources resource are found.
If I remove the configuration above for the SharedResources then specific resource files are respected.

Comment: Hi @Lucho Gizdov, this is the expected result.  If you configure it in Program.cs, the whole project will always use it and the Program.cs is global configuration.

Comment: So, I can't use 1 share resource file and specific resource files for data-annonations?

Comment: Hi @Lucho Gizdov, that's it.